# Is there a difference between "assertion" and "assertation"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

In software development we use the word **`Assert`** frequently. While working I had to describe some of the code I was working on. I was going to write that...

> This function makes the **assertion** that x is expected to be y.

While writing the sentence, *which I actually have not yet finished*, I had the realization that I could also write...

> This function makes the **assertation** that x is expected to be y.

I got stuck trying to figure out if there was a difference between the two words:

1. Assertion
2. Assertation

I noticed quickly that *assertation* is red-lighted by my spell-checker, however, I was positive that *assertation* is a word. I did the obvious thing to do for any similar situation, and referred to a dictionary (I like Webster, so that's what I used).

**Here is what the Webster American English Dictionary had to say:**

> **[Definition of Assertion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assertion)**
>
> : the act of asserting or something that is asserted: such as
>
> - a : insistent and positive affirming, maintaining, or defending (as of a right or attribute) an assertion of ownership/innocence
> - b : a declaration that something is the case He presented no evidence to support his assertions.
>
> — **Webster Dictionary**

> **[Definition of Assertation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assertation)**
>
> - : the act of asserting or something that is asserted : assertion
>
> — **Webster Dictionary**

---

At this point I still can't find a difference, or at least I don't see one. I also don't understand why *assertation* is being flagged by my spell checker, because the Webster online dictionary shows *assertation* being used in all sorts of published articles & documents.

Does anyone know if there is a reason I shouldn't use *assertation*, or if there is a difference between the two words?
The only thing I can think of is that either: The difference is contingent on context, one is preferred by British English speakers, or that there is no difference.

If there is no difference, any notes on why there are two versions would be helpful.

Comment: I'd go with the shorter of most choices, but Americans often swing that way. Also, since I hear conversate (from conversation), I'd be scared of **assertate** coming back at me.

Comment: It's not uncommon for use of a normal term in a novel environment to reset the morphology, like _Toronto Maple Leafs_ instead of _Leaves_. This may be done on purpose, the way Grice coined the term _implicature_ (instead of _implication_, which already had a formal meaning) for propositions derived from the conversational context instead of the meaning.

Comment: Cf *oriented* vs *orientated*

Comment: As for why "assertation" is flagged: although it got a dictionary entry, it's [orders of magnitude less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assertion%2Cassertation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cassertion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cassertation%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I have never seen assertation in my entire life and frankly, I could care less if it is in the dictionary. Lots of things are in dictionaries. That doesn't mean we use them...

Comment: Only 56,700 results for "assertation" compared to 13,70,00,000 results for "assertion" on Google. I would go with the more common term and one which doesn't trip the spell-checker.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Thats actually a really clever point.

Comment: @AndyBonner Wow, great insight. _oriented & orientated_, its the same type of situation, isn't it. I guess I am free to choose either. Still it begs the question, why is there two words for the same thing? How do these conundrums come to be? I am probably over thinking it a bit, but occasionally I have to write technical excerpts that document APIs (Application Programming Interfaces), and its important that they are explained very precisely. To be as precise as I can possibly be, the English I choose to use needs to be proper.

Comment: @Lambie Why did you say you care whether it's in the dictionary?

Comment: Spell checkers only *suggest* that the word in question *might* be misspelled.

Comment: @tchrist As most people know the colloquial expression is could care less even if the nha nha nha-ers prefer could not care less.

Comment: The full OED says ***assertation*** is "Obsolete. rare".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Robert Hartwell Fiske's [*Dictionary of Unendurable English*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=JZqfZfIvtlsC&pg=PA60&dq=%22assertation%22+%22obsolete%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiz7MbD3OH2AhVPrVYBHTdhA80Q6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22assertation%22%20%22obsolete%22&f=false):

> **assertation** Misused for *assertion*.
>
> - I would dispute your *assertation*. USE *assertion*.
> - I can't say enough that this *assertation* is categorically, absolutely, and unconditionally wrong. USE *assertion*.
> - Given Miller's *assertation* that he knew of "at least three" teams willing to pay Boozer's $10.97 million salary, it appears that other teams have called to inquire about the forward. USE *assertion*.
>
> *Assertation*, a thoroughly **obsolete** word used by fearfully modern people, is incorrect for *assertion*. *Assertation*—like the equally preposterous *documentate* (instead of *document*) and *opinionation* (instead of *opinion*)—is spoken or written by people who do not well know the words they use, by people who do not often read, by people who do not cavil over adding a syllable or two to a word: humanity lies elsewhere.

There's no difference between the two words, but I would use the more common<sup>[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/586580/assertion-vs-assertation#comment1469188_586580)</sup> <sup>[2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assertion%2Cassertation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cassertion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cassertation%3B%2Cc0)</sup>, rather, *correct* term, i.e., *assertion*.

Comment: Wow, this answer offers far more than I ever expected from an answer. My understanding, from reading the answer above, is that `assertion` is constructed from contemporary syllables, where `assertate` is an older implementation of the same same word. A modern English speaker, especially those who study English, should not use older implementations of words, because it doesn't help to progress society, or the English language. In fact, the use of such words, can hinder progressiveness, consequently; the use of assertate is actually frowned upon by some.

Comment: This is a fabulous answer! I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

OED:

> † assertation, n. ***Obsolete. rare.* Affirmation, assertion.**
>
> a1535   T. More Wks. (R.) 141 (R.)   *Bothe ye confuting of theirs, and..the assertacion of our owne.*

And Google Ngrams: **[assertion,assertation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assertion%2Cassertation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cassertion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cassertation%3B%2Cc0)**

Comment: Obsolete and rare?

Comment: You tell me.... The Ngram is there...

Comment: As obsolete as hens' teeth.

Comment: But may still be used in historical novels, etc. i.e. rarely

Comment: 'This function makes the assertation that x is expected to be y' famously appearing in Emma?

Answer (score 1):

A review of [Google Books results for "assertation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22assertation%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) shows a niche use: many of the results are from 1970s-1980s works in psychology about "assertation training." This seems to amount to a usage similar to "assertiveness," and indeed "assertiveness training" is found with a similar spike in the same time period.

If the question is "then why choose 'assertation training'" over "assertiveness training": I can't find enough material to verify, but I might speculate that such authors felt that "assertiveness" could be perceived as a character trait, but "assertation" as an activity or skill (and wanted to avoid "assertion" because they were differentiating between "an assertion," an individual expression, and "assertation," presumably a pattern of behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Simply,  British English... Assertion is the belief a stament is true, whereas, Attestation is the fact of a true statement.

Assertion, noun.
A statement that you strongly believe is true.

Attestation, noun.
A formal statement that you make and officially say is true.

I hope this clears it up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, Dee Tee. The question doesn't mention 'attestation'.